# Is $T:X-X$ as $T(f(x))=\int_0^{x}f(t)dt,\; \forall f\in X$.one-one onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $X=C(0,1)$. Define $T:X-X$ as $T(f(x))=\int_0^{x}f(t)dt,\; \forall f\in X$.
Then I have to determine if the mapping is one-one onto or not.

For one-one

$T(f(x))=T(g(x))$

$\Rightarrow \int_0^{x}f(t)dt=\int_0^{x}g(t)dt$

Differentiating with respect to $x$

$\Rightarrow f(x)=g(x)$. Hence one-one.

For onto I am not sure,

$T(f(x))=\int_0^{x}f(t)dt$ according to me means that whatever function we input, we would get something that is dependent on $x$. Hence we won't be able to get any constant functions which do belong in $X$

Is this correct?

Comment: Two ways for _not_ onto here. (1) For any $f\in C(0,1)$, $T(f)$, as per your definition, is absolutely continuous. However, $C(0,1)$ itself contains continuous functions that are _not_ absolutely continuous. Hence $T$ is _not_ onto. (2) For $g=T(f)$, it is a must that $g(0)=0$. But $C(0,1)$ includes the continuous functions whose value at $x=0$ is nonzero. Hence $T$ is _not_ onto.

Comment: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and $T(f)$ is differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not onto, since, for each $f\in X$, $T(f)(0)=0$. So, for instance, the constant function $1$ does not belong to the range of $T$.

Comment: so it is not onto right?

Comment: Right. I wrote “into” in my answer, but it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

If $g \in T(X)$, then $g(x)=\int_0^{x}f(t)dt$ for some $f \in X$. Since $f$ is continuous, g is differentiable.

Conclusion: if $g \in X$ is not differentiable, then $g \notin T(X).$

We have $T(X)=C^1(0,1)$.

Comment: what is $C^1(0,1)$?

Comment: the  class of differentiable functions with continuous derivative